# Maintain the sequence order of the key from a MapType when extracting the key value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do I maintain the same sequence order of the key from a `MapType` when extracting the key value? The data is loaded from an avro file and the schema of the avro file is as below.

```python
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (
            "a-key", 
            {"FName": "John", "LName": "Citizen", "Age":"30","Mobile":"00000000" }, 
            "John" 
        )
    ], 
    ["somekey", "metadata", "name", ]
)

df.select(explode(df.metadata)).show()
```

I believe out of sequence order of the key is due to partitioning

```
+------+--------+
|   key|   value|
+------+--------+
| LName| Citizen|
|Mobile|00000000|
| FName|    John|
|   Age|      30|
+------+--------+
```

I am expecting the below output i.e. the same sequence as defined in the DataFrame.

```
+------+--------+
|   key|   value|
+------+--------+
| FName|    John|
| LName| Citizen|
|   Age|      30|
|Mobile|00000000|
+------+--------+
```

Comment: Do not rely on the sequence of rows in a spark DataFrame. Spark DataFrames do not have a concept of order, which is what allows for each row to be processed independently in parallel. (You can force order by specifying a column for sorting.)

Answer (score 1):

The change in the order is due to Python `dict` type. A Python dictionary is not an ordered object, and therefore, the data are sent to spark in a certain order which may be different from the one you wanted.

If you read directly a file, or a table with Spark, the same issue should not appear.

But after that, the `explode` does not respect the order in the map. Therefore you need to use [`posexplode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode) function.

Comment: `df.select(posexplode(df.metadata)).collect()
[Row(pos=0, key=u'LName', value=u'Citizen'), Row(pos=1, key=u'Mobile', value=u'00000000'), Row(pos=2, key=u'FName', value=u'John'), Row(pos=3, key=u'Age', value=u'30')]
` **Position explode not possible**

Comment: @Prathik did you read what I wrote ? I'm not saying `posexplode` will fix the issue, I'm saying the issue comes from the fact that he uses both Python dict and explode.

Comment: @Steven I am reading directly from an avro file and the sequence of the Key is out of order. Like you mentioned it is of type dict, so I think we have no control on the order.  Can you think of other methods to get Key in the orginal sequence.